# PHP strange behaviour using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code implemented in PHP:

```
function attemptDBConnection($shouldRedirect){

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mydb");


    if ($con->connect_errno && shouldRedirect)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        header("Location: ./errorPages/nodbconnection.html");
    }


    return $con;
}


function isAlreadyRegistered($con){



    $email=$_POST["email"];





    $testSelectUser=$con->stmt_init();
    $testSelectUser->prepare("SELECT * from User WHERE email=?;");
    $testSelectUser->bind_param("s",$email);
    $testSelectUser->execute();
    $resultUser=$testSelectUser->get_result();
    $rowsUser=mysqli_num_rows($resultUser);

    return $rowsUser>0;



}

    $con=attemptDBConnection(true);

    if(isAlreadyRegistered($con)){
    header("Location: ./errorPages/alreadyregistered.html");
    mysqli_close($con);
    exit;
    }
```

And the following thing is happening: when attemptDBConnection is called mysqli_connect executes ok and no errno set for $con, at this point $con->affected_rows is 0. $con->connect_errno is zero so the if is never entered, but after the condition is set $con->affected_rows is set to -1 dunno why!

$con is then returned.

When the isAlreadyRegistered function executes, the execute call returns true but $testUserSelect->affected_rows is set to -1 but the errno is 0 . the next call to get_result() never returns.

What could be causing this to happen? What am I doing wrong?

PHP is quite new to me and I've been unable to figure out what's happening here.
Thank you.

EDIT:

some tests I've made: if I replace the isAlreadyRegistered() function for this:

```
function isAlreadyRegistered($con){



$email=$_POST["email"];





$testSelectUser=$con->stmt_init();
$testSelectUser->prepare("SELECT * from User WHERE email='myemail@gmail.com';");
$testSelectUser->execute();
$resultUser=$testSelectUser->get_result();
$rowsUser=mysqli_num_rows($resultUser);

return $rowsUser>0;



}
```

Then I get the same result.

if instead I do:

```
    function isAlreadyRegistered($con){



    $email=$_POST["email"];

    $testSelectDoc="SELECT * from ask2doc.Medico WHERE email='myemail@gmail.com';";

    $resultDoc=mysqli_query($con,$testSelectDoc);

    $rowsDoc=mysqli_num_rows ($resultDoc );


    return $rowsDoc>0;



}
```

Then it works. Any idea why?

Comment: @Svetlio This is not true from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php: `For SELECT statements mysqli_affected_rows() works like mysqli_num_rows(). `

Comment: @Jim you are correct.. Strange I haven't used it ever for selects its doesn't sounds right..

Comment: @Svetlio Yeah it's strange. For readability I'd always use the more appropriate num_rows.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) -1 indicates an error in the last query.

Check `$testSelectUser->error` but it's likely the query you are using is wrong.

Comment: @Svetlio The asker says `after the condition is set $con->affected_rows is set to -1 dunno why`. Affected rows will return the count of rows for non update/insert queries.

Comment: error is zero at all times either for the mysqli obj or for the mysqli_stmt obj... at all times!! thats the strange thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this fast code (not tested I hope it works..) :)

```
function isAlreadyRegistered($con){
    $email= !empty($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : '';

    $testSelectUser=$con->stmt_init();
    $testSelectUser->prepare("SELECT * from User WHERE email=?;");
    $testSelectUser->bind_param("s",$email);
    $testSelectUser->execute();
    $testSelectUser->store_result();
    return $testSelectUser->num_rows > 0;
}
```

Comment: $_POST["email"] is set... I'm using the debugger and it is properly set.